# MYOB ODBC connection error

Tags: c#, odbc, database-connection, connection-string, myob

I recently got a prebuild application which is uses a MYOB ODBC connection to a MYOB file.
The ODBC connection works perfectly in that application.

I'm using the same ODBC connection string in another application but it failed to open in that application. The connection string is perfectly identical but it won't work there.

The error I'm getting is:

**ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**

The server explorer in Visual Studio 2008 connects without a problem with the same connection string.

Is it a trusted application issue because my new application is not digitally signed at the moment?

```
OdbcConnection odbc = new OdbcConnection("Driver=MYOAU0901;TYPE=MYOB; UID=Administrator; PWD=; DATABASE=C:\\Premier125\\Clearwtr.MYO; NETWORK_PROTOCOL=NONET; DRIVER_COMPLETION=DRIVER_NOPROMPT;;KEY=****");
odbc.Open();
```

The key used in the connection string is definitely valid.

kindly help me.

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: hi john gietzen
i am getting the following exception
ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: Was this under 32-bit Windows, or 64?

Answer (score 1):

MYOB ODBC does not require your application to be signed. The company file must be registered for ODBC to allow reads, and you must install a licence key to allow writes. I am assuming your new application is running on the same machine as the company file and MYOB executable, and that your company file is properly registered.

1. Try setting the KEY parameter to the key itself, not a path to a key file.
2. Replace ;; with ;
3. Include the key HOST_EXE_PATH in your connection string. This is the path to the MYOB executable (in your case this will be myobp.exe).
4. If you still have no luck, try setting up a User DSN. This will allow you to test whether everything is installed correctly. If the DSN works, you can try replacing your connection string with a reference to the DSN, so "DSN=YourDsnName".